# Pushing files on github

Tags: linux, git, github

To push files onto a repository on github do I have to manually create the repository on github before that?
I got the following error if I don't create the repository automatically:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a repository if you want to push to one. See [this GitHub tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote)

GitHub allows you to create a repo with files in it already, too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: see [this Github article on pushing to a remote repository](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote) for detailed instructions on pushing to remotes.